# python Importerror using jsonrpc2

Tags: python, importerror, json-rpc

I am trying jsonrpc2 using python. I created a file hello.py

```
def greeting(name):
    return dict(message="Hello, %s!" % name)
```

Then I run

```
runjsonrpc2 hello
```

but i got

```
ImportError: No module named hello
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `runjsonrpc2` is not able to find the `hello.py` module in the `sys.path`.

You can augment the search path including the directory where your `hello` module lays just setting the [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) environment variable.

For example, if you are using a bash shell, you can run the following commands in the same directory of your `hello.py` file:

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:.
$ runjsonrpc2 hello
```

Comment: Yes, it is the problem of path. My system is windows7. I used $env:PYTHONPATH="mypath" . it works.